# Can this sentence be worded in this way?

Tags: grammar

Instead of saying:
I was eating a steak, and John was eating the lunch he brought from home.

Could I word it as such:

I was eating a steak, and John the lunch he brought from home.

Comment: Sai, yes, you can. If any, there is to say that the second form is better English than the former.

Answer (score 3):

The second formation is better as it has no redundant and the verb 'was eating', serves both your steak and John's lunch.

The first formation, where 'was eating' is repeated twice, suffers from redundancy and hence not a 'good' sentence structure, even though it is grammatically correct.